# Rewrite url instead of redirect?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following rules in .htaccess file that are supposed to rewrite URL's not containing index.php in them

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?q=$1
```

So, I wanted to open in my browser http://example.com/website.com, and to have returned response under that url, however instead of that I get redirected to http://example.com/index.php?q=website.com.  Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: Put `[L]` flag at the end of your rule

Comment: Tried that, same thing

Comment: This actually works, it was my index.php that was doing redirect